# Browser not starting up on using "at" scheduling command?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm running this shell command using `at`

Basically, I'm starting up firefox browser using the command `firefox`

`echo 'firefox' | at 18:35 04/02/2015`

Although the browser starts up on entering `firefox` in terminal. The above `at` command produces no result even after the timeframe has passed

What am i missing?

Comment: Perhaps the $DISPLAY variable is not set in the `at` daemon.

Comment: @user4098326 I'm finding no additional process on `ps -ef` on that exact scheduled time

Comment: Firefox exits immediately if $DISPLAY is unset when run.

Comment: @user4098326: `at` explicitly (`man at`) retains the environment _"except for the variables `BASH_VERSINFO`, `DISPLAY`, `EUID`, `GROUPS`, `SHELLOPTS`, `TERM`, `UID`, and `_`"_, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
echo firefox > myjob
chmod 755 myjob
at -f myjob now + 1 hour
```

What you are doing is trying to echo a word through at.  You need to give it a command to execute. You can do that interactively (less common) or put the job in a file (script) and execute it (more common).

Comment: Is there any way i can run this without having to create a file or running with `at -f` ?

Comment: @wolfgang: you're doing it right, `at` will read commands from standard input. Use `at -c (jobid)` to see what `atd` will execute.